Yarn Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/home' MacOS
Why is yarn trying to get into the home directive? Why does it even need to do that? And how to change this moment.
I had something happen to yarn, it started trying to run as a different user. I deleted the user and reinstalled yarn.
sudo yarn add eslint -W --verbose
Password:
yarn add v1.22.22
verbose 0.083334667 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/.npmrc".
verbose 0.083452292 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/share/.npmrc".
verbose 0.083559375 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.083625125 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.npmrc".
verbose 0.083790292 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/.npmrc".
verbose 0.083866875 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/.npmrc".
verbose 0.08399075 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.npmrc".
verbose 0.084125834 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.npmrc".
verbose 0.084445167 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084497542 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/share/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084628 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.084702167 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084797375 Found configuration file "/Users/yurii/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084909709 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/datarama_frontend/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084961125 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/projects/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.084999125 Checking for configuration file "/Users/yurii/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.085033167 Found configuration file "/Users/yurii/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.085195334 Checking for configuration file "/Users/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.086573875 current time: 2024-04-25T10:37:13.802Z
glob error [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/home'] {
errno: -1,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/home'
}
verbose 0.13707675 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/home'
error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/home'
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
echo $HOME
/Users/yurii
echo $YARN_CACHE_FOLDER
<empty_string>
echo $NODE_PATH
<empty_string>
cat ~/.yarnrc
THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
yarn lockfile v1
cache-folder "yarn-cache"
lastUpdateCheck 1714037047147
cat ~/.npmrc
cat: /Users/yurii/.npmrc: No such file or directory
